# Send And Receive string between Arduino and iOS Device via UDP

Tags: ios, objective-c, udp, arduino

I need to send and receive data between Arduino and iOS Device via UDP. Can I use example from official Arduino site: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/UDPSendReceiveString. If yes, how can send strings from iOS device. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use example from official [Arduino site](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/UDPSendReceiveString).

Yes

> If yes, how can send strings from iOS device.

Well, first you need to use an Arduino Ethernet Shield, or an Arduino Ethernet.

Then, you need to have your iOS device on the same network as your Arduino (or at least to have the iOS and Arduino IP address accessible from each other, however you manage to do it).

Finally, just read thoroughly the tutorial you linked, try the example, adapt the addresses from the example with your use case.

My advice to you is to first use a computer to test the UDP connection with the Arduino, and then use that computer to test the UDP connection with the iOS device, and once you know both works independently, make the connection work with both devices.

Comment: Understand, But I need UDP tutorial for iOS. Can I use AsyncUDPSocket?